# Error in installing software from the Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center

I started using Ubuntu a few days ago, so please a little help would be cool.
Whenever I try to install a package from the Ubuntu Software Center it gives me the following error for everything. Can anyone explain?

```
Requires installation of untrusted packages
This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources.
Details 
libaacs0 libbluray1 libcddb2 libcrystalhd3 libdvbpsi7 libebml3 libiso9660-8 libmatroska5 libresid-builder0c2a libsdl-image1.2 libsdl1.2debian libsidplay2 libssh2-1 libtar0 libupnp6 libva-x11-1 libvcdinfo0 libwebp4 libxcb-keysyms1
```

Comment: try: sudo apt-get update .hope this'll help !

Comment: Go to Settings->Software & updates-> Other software->check the box "Independent" and "Canonical partners".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other wise you may try as

```
sudo apt-get install libaacs0 libbluray1 libcddb2 libcrystalhd3 libdvbpsi7 libebml3 libiso9660-8 libmatroska5 libresid-builder0c2a libsdl-image1.2 libsdl1.2debian libsidplay2 libssh2-1 libtar0 libupnp6 libva-x11-1 libvcdinfo0 libwebp4 libxcb-keysyms1
```

from your terminal and then the remaining installation you can continue either from terminal or from USC, :)

Comment: wow.. so basically i install all of those?

Comment: I'm getting that error even for standard Ubuntu updates..i mean for stuff like security updates?